# incrementing a counter for every object

Tags: c++, dictionary

I have a class called `Student`, and in that class I have a `std::map` of books that looks like this:

```
std::map<std::string,int>books;
```

The `string` is the book name, and the `int` is the number of students that have the same book.

Then I create a new `Student`, and when I do I want that `Student` to also get the same books, so I do a copy like this:

```
new_student->getBookmap() = old_student->getBookmap();
new_student_3->getBookmap() = old_student->getBookmap();
```

`getBookmap()` returns the `map` for each `Student`. I have them as `private` members.

The new `Student` gets the exact copy of the same `map`, and now I want to increase the counter, but the counter should also be increased for all three `Student`s.

But, if I increase the counter for one `Student`, the other `Student`s' counters don't increase.

```
for (auto it = new_student->getBookmap().begin(); it != new_student->getBookmap().end(); it++)
{
    it->second++;
}
```

When I do this, the counter only increases for the `new_student`, and not for `old_student` and `new_student_1`.

Could someone help me out?

Comment: Sounds like you want to use shared references to fixed maps, rather than making copies of maps. In fact, I think you only ever need **one** map.

Comment: Move the map outside of the `Student` class.  Anything having to do with multiple students should not be in a single student class.

Comment: This question's shown code fails to meet Stackoverflow's requirements for showing a [mre]. Because of that it's unlikely that anyone here can conclusively answer the question; but only guess at the most. You need to [edit] your question to show a minimal example, no more than one or two pages of code (the "minimal" part), that everyone else can cut/paste ***exactly as shown***, compile, run, and reproduce the described issue (the "reproducible" part, this includes any ancillary information, like any input to the program). See [ask] for more information.

Comment: Student should no have this field. IMO you need another class for example called  `Library` or `BookCollection` or ... .

Comment: @AdrianMole yeah you are right, how could I make shared reference to a fixed map?

Comment: `int i; int& r1 = i; int& r2 = i; int& r3 = i;` All three references refer to the same `int`.

Comment: @AdrianMole how would i do this in my own case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that each `Student` object has its own copy of the `std::map`.  You need them to share a single `std::map` object instead.

The simplest way to share the `books` field is to make it a `static` member of `Student`, then you don't need to copy it around at all, eg:

```
using bookCounter = std::map<std::string, int>;

class Student {
private:
    static bookCounter books;
    ...
    void checkoutBook(std::string bookName);
    void returnBook(std::string bookName);
    ...
};
```

```
bookCounter Student::books;

void Student::checkoutBook(std::string bookName)
{
    books[bookName]++;
}

void Student::returnBook(std::string bookName)
{
    books[bookName]--;
}
```

```
int main()
{
    ...
    new_student = new Student();
    new_student->checkoutBook("...");
    ...
    new_student->returnBook("...");
    ...
}
```

Or, you can declare `books` as a global variable, say near `main()`, and then just refer to that variable inside of `Students` when needed, eg:

```
class Student {
    ...
};

using bookCounter = std::map<std::string, int>;
extern bookCounter books;
```

```
void Student::checkoutBook(std::string bookName)
{
    books[bookName]++;
}

void Student::returnBook(std::string bookName)
{
    books[bookName]--;
}
```

```
bookCounter books;

int main()
{
    ...
}
```

Or, you could make `books` be a local variable of `main()` itself, and then you can pass a pointer/reference to it to each `Student`, eg:

```
using bookCounter = std::map<std::string, int>;

class Student {
private:
    bookCounter &books;
    ...
public:
    Student(bookCounter &books) : books(books) {}
    ...
    void checkoutBook(std::string bookName);
    void returnBook(std::string bookName);
    ...
};
```

```
void Student::checkoutBook(std::string bookName)
{
    books[bookName]++;
}

void Student::returnBook(std::string bookName)
{
    books[bookName]--;
}
```

```
int main()
{
    bookCounter books;
    ...
    new_student = new Student(books);
    new_student->checkoutBook("...");
    ...
    new_student->returnBook("...");
    ...
}
```

Alternatively, you might consider using `std::shared_ptr` to share a single `std::map` object amongst the various `Student` objects, eg:

```
using bookCounter = std::map<std::string, int>;

class Student {
private:
    std::shared_ptr<bookCounter> books;
    ...
public:
    Student(std::shared_ptr<bookCounter> books) : books(books) {}
    ...
    void checkoutBook(std::string bookName);
    void returnBook(std::string bookName);
    ...
};
```

```
void Student::checkoutBook(std::string bookName)
{
    (*books)[bookName]++;
}

void Student::returnBook(std::string bookName)
{
    (*books)[bookName]--;
}
```

```
int main()
{
    auto books = std::make_shared<bookCounter>();
    ...
    new_student = new Student(books);
    new_student->checkoutBook("...");
    ...
    new_student->returnBook("...");
    ...
}
```

In which case, you might instead consider changing the `std::map` into a `std::vector` of `std::shared_ptr<Book>` objects, to share individual book objects rather then just strings, and not manage your own counters at all (`std::shared_ptr` has its own counter, which you can query via its [`use_count()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/use_count) method), eg:

```
struct Book : std::enable_shared_from_this<Book>
{
    std::string name;
    ...
    int checkoutCount() const;

    [[nodiscard]] static std::shared_ptr<Book> create();

private:
    Book() = default;
};
using bookPtr = std::shared_ptr<Book>;

class Student {
private:
    std::vector<bookPtr> books;
    ...
public:
    ...
    void checkoutBook(std::string bookName);
    void returnBook(std::string bookName);
    ...
};
```

```
std::vector<bookPtr> library;

std::shared_ptr<Book> Book::create()
{
    return std::shared_ptr<Book>(new Book);
}

int Book::checkoutCount() const
{
    auto pthis = shared_from_this();
    return (pthis.use_count() - 2); // not counting pthis and the library ...
}

void Student::checkoutBook(std::string bookName)
{
    auto iter = std::find_if(library.begin(), library.end(),
        [&](bookPtr &book){ return book->name == bookName; }
    );
    if (iter != library.end())
        books.push_back(*iter);
}

void Student::returnBook(std::string bookName)
{
    auto iter = std::find_if(books.begin(), books.end(),
        [&](bookPtr &book){ return book->name == bookName; }
    );
    if (iter != books.end())
        books.erase(*iter);
}
```

```
int main()
{
    // populate library with Books as needed...
    ...
    new_student = new Student();
    new_student->checkoutBook("...");
    ...
    new_student->returnBook("...");
    ...
}
```